# Secret variables with a dollar sign are not correctly set

Tags: gitlab, cicd, gitlab-runner

when trying to use a secret variable with a value containing dollar sign on gitlab-ci secret variables it's not got variable value correctly.

Comment: This is discussed in depth over here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27436

Answer (score 5):

the solution is to set the dollar sign twice, for example, if your variable value is `123$567` put it like this: `123$$567`

Answer (score 1):

While [escaping `$` (with `$$`)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-the--character-in-variables) is one way, but [GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#support-the--character-in-cicd-variables) (December 2022) adds another option:

> ### Support the `$` character in CI/CD variables
>
> Support the `$` character in CI/CD variables
>
> Previously, using the `$` character in a CI/CD variable always indicated the start of a reference another variable, which GitLab then tried to expand.
> As a result, you could not have a value with a `$` as part of the string unless it was [escaped](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-the--character-in-variables), which can be confusing.
>
> In this release, we are introducing a new setting for project, group, and instance CI/CD variables.
>
> You can now toggle whether or not GitLab interprets the CI/CD variable as a raw string, or treats a `$` as the start of another variable that should be expanded.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_7/raw.png -- Support the $ character in CI/CD variables]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#expand-cicd-variables) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17069).